# codeigniter force_download leaving empty space

Tags: php, codeigniter, force-download

I'm having an issue, which seems like a bug, whereby if I download a CSV that I've created it seems to leave 12 empty spaces on the top of the file before filling in the content I want in there.

Is this just a general bug?

I'm using Codeigniter 2.1.3

Thanks Guys

Comment: Sounds like extra whitespace after of before the first/last `<?php` or `?>` in one or some of your files (config files, controllers...). You can leave off the trailing `?>` and it makes it easier to avoid these problems. Can you verify this?

Comment: It seems as if it is leaving the white place because somewhere in my code there is a gap being left in the html pages once they are loaded. Why this is is another question in itself

Comment: In newer versions of CI, there's an output buffer started for every request, so as a last resort you can always throw away any output generated before with `ob_clean()` you print the csv output.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same issue. When I looked through my code I was calling in a model that had a closing ?> tag, and for some weird reason, that created the extra space. Look to see if you have any closing php tags.

Answer (score -1):

i had the issue too. But i solve it not related to closing ?>, but space in the beginning of php file. use tools such as winHex to open related php files, look if the file start with a space(in Hex it's 20), remove it, and the problem had solved.

sorry for my poor english.